# Extending package name android

Tags: android, android-studio, package, rename, extend

I have a question about extending package name in android studio. I know how to refactor existing name to some other, but what i want to do is add one more extension. 
For example i want to change com.google.something.app to com.google.extension.something.app 
Is this possible to do and how to do it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible to do

Yes.

> how to do it?

Step #1: Right-click over `java/` in the project tree and choose New > Package

Step #2: Type in the new package name and click OK

Step #3: Refactor the class into the newly-created package (e.g., via drag-and-drop)

Comment: @Pani: I do not know what errors you are expecting to see here. Have you tried it? Create a scrap project and experiment with the technique.

Comment: Because i tried to replace all mentions of old package name for new package name and it found almost 1000 hits where it should replace it. It did not work, but it seems not enough just to do what you are suggesting. I will try tough

Comment: @Pani: "Because i tried to replace all mentions of old package name for new package name and it found almost 1000 hits where it should replace it" -- the package name references are fixed up by Android Studio, as part of the refactoring process. Again: create a scrap project and experiment with the technique.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There was a great way of doing this in Android Studio 2.3, but I haven't found that same option in >= AS 3.0.

Anyhow, the package is just a folder name. Open it in Finder (for Mac) and add a folder at whatever level you need it, and move the folders coming after into that newly created one instead.

As in the image below - just create an `extension` folder at appropriate level in the package hierarchy, an move `something` into `extension`.

[image]